# how i save html data in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have saved some HTML data in mysql using php 64base_encode function

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = base64_encode($_POST['content']);
$sqlTestimonail = "INSERT INTO staticpages (title, content) VALUES ('" . $title . "', '" . $content . "')";
```

//above code is stroing values in mysql

but when i fetch this and want to show this as HTML it will print it like string instead of rendering it as HTML
I am  using 64base_decode function to show
below is my code

```
   <main class="ps-main">
        <div class="ps-banner">
            <?php include('includes/slider.php'); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!----here we cut banner html and show this in static page -->
    <?php
    $printContent = "banner";
    $sql_static_banner = "select * from staticpages where title='" . $printContent . "'";
    $query_static_banner = mysqli_query($con, $sql_static_banner);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query_static_banner) > 0) {
        $print_static_banner = mysqli_fetch_array($query_static_banner);
        echo base64_decode($print_static_banner['content']);
    }
    ?>
    <div class="ps-section--features-product ps-section masonry-root pt-40 pb-80"></div>
```

if i view page source than echoed variable data show like this

```
<div>&nbsp;&lt;div class="ps-section masonry-root pt-80 pb-40"&gt;</div><div>
```

Comment: this is absolutely NOT how you should store  HTML data in mysql in the first place

Answer (score -1):

You didnt show the code to store the data in the database. Maybe before it is stored it goes through htmlspecialchars? Anyway if you base64 encode/decode it should not be needed.

To address this issue you can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php to convert special entities to characters.

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode('&nbsp;&lt;div class="ps-section masonry-root pt-80 pb-40"&gt;');
&nbsp;<div class="ps-section masonry-root pt-80 pb-40">
```

So in your case `echo base64_decode($print_static_banner['content']);` becomes `echo htmlspecialchars_decode(base64_decode($print_static_banner['content']));`

Comment: encoding and decoding data back and forth makes absolutely no sense

Comment: @YourCommonSense there was no info about what the source of data is when I added the answer and there is nothing about adding encoding here either.

Comment: A direct answer is not always the best answer